# Problem with NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I declared a NSMutable array and assigned some values to it.

```
.h
NSMutableArray *imageDetailsFromCategory;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imageDetailsFromCategory;

.m
@synthesise imageDetailsFromCategory

in ViewDidLoad:

imageDetailsFromCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//assigning object to Array..working fine.showing two images.
imageDetailsFromCategory = [self  getImageDetailsFromCategory:generatedString];
```

Now my app is loading... I am doing some UI changes with the array. However I want to pass this array on another button click to another class. But when click event is triggered  the array shows `0x76779e0"{(int)$VAR Count}` like this in the same class I declared the arry. I can't get the array count after the button click.

Can any one tell me how can I access my array. What is the problem?

Comment: Add code tags to your question. It's hardly understandable.

Comment: It looks like the getImageDetailsFromCategory method is overwriting imageDetailsFromCategory. Please post the code for this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `[self getImageDetailsFromCategory:generatedString];` I think returns a `autoreleased` array. Try using the proper setter for retaining it, like

```
self.imageDetailsFromCategory = [self getImageDetailsFromCategory:generatedString];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding your `imageDetailsFromCategory` variable that you alloc'd in the first line with your second line.

So `imageDetailsFromCategory = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` creates a mutable array… but `imageDetailsFromCategory = [self  getImageDetailsFromCategory:generatedString];` replaces the previously alloced mutable array with a brand new object.

THat's as if you did `int i=5;` then `i = [self someMethod];`: the value 5 would be lost.